# Android access string in same activity

Tags: android, string

I have error "mystring cannot be resolved to a variable", How can i Access String in same activity.

```
String mystring = null;
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  mystring = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();
  Toast.makeText(this, mystring, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void setAdapterToListview() {
    objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    isloading = false;
    listView.removeFooterView(footer);
    int TOTAL_ITMES = 0;

    try {
        TOTAL_ITMES = Integer.parseInt(mystring);
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

    }

    if (mainArrayList != null && mainArrayList.size() >= TOTAL_ITMES) {
        System.out.println("Total Size ::"+mainArrayList.size());
        hasMore = false;
    }
}
```

Toast working fine... but String name "mystring" Not possible accses in this line

```
TOTAL_ITMES = Integer.parseInt(mystring);
```

How can i?

Comment: declare mystring globally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `myString` outside the `onItemClick` method

```
String mystring = null;
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  mystring = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();
}
```

You need to understand the [*Scope of a variable*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) before you begin coding.

Comment: Now Mystring is null only now work..Not possible show string outside onitemclick...

Comment: Hello sir.. i edited, check again. Toast working fine... outside onItemClick string is now null only

Comment: Initialise `String mystring = "0"`. Then it wont return null when you access `setAdapterToListview()`

Comment: No i need pass mystring value from onItemClick... i nee that value in this line TOTAL_ITMES = Integer.parseInt(mystring);

Comment: Then call 
`setAdapterToListview(mystring)` after showing the `Toast` in `OnItemClick` . That should be plainly visible right?

Comment: setAdapterToListview(mystring) not work. How can i pass "mystring" value outside onItemClick?????.. i added final not work...ur code only retrieve null or "0". Not retrive mystring value from onitemclick..

Comment: After this `mystring = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();` call `setAdapterToListview(mystring)`

Comment: You need basic lessons in programming brother. Change method signature of `setAdapterToListview()` to `public void setAdapterToListview(String mystring)`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the string again from the TextView in setAdapterToListview or declare it as a member variable of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt() will throw a NumberFormatExcption,  if the string provided is not a proper number. Similarly you can convert, String to Float, String to Double. Java API provide static method Float.parseFloat(),   Double.parseDouble() for data type conversion.